# Equal spacing between characters with stroke between letter

Tags: php, html, css, safari, flexbox

I'm working on a website right now for a client where they need the header of each page to have a word stretching from left to right on the page with a black line between each character.

With the help of @Paulie_D I managed to set up a flex property on this site http://s-p-o-k.se/web/om-spok/ using this code:

```
<div id="header-text">
<span class="first"><img src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/images/Oo.svg"></span>
<span><img src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/images/M.svg"></span>
</div>

#header-text {
width: 100%;
display: flex;
justify-content:;
font-weight: 700;
font-family: 'pduregular';
color: #000;
max-width: 100%;
height: 160px;
}

#header-text span {
display: -webkit-box;
display: -moz-box;
display: -ms-flexbox;
display: -webkit-flex;
display: flex;
flex: 1;
align-items: center;
}

#header-text span::after {
content: ' ';
flex: 1;
height: 15px;
background: #000;
}

#header-text span:last-child {
flex: 0;
margin-left: 10px;
}
```

This works well in Firefox but in Safari it doesn't show the last child. I tried looking around but I couldn't find what could cause that. Does anyone have an idea?

Best regards, Marcus

Comment: Here's the original question and my solution - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35336960/equal-spacing-between-characters-with-stroke-in-between

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has to do with chrome/safari not handling image correctly as flex childs (they are shrinked or expanded, here shrinked to zero width).

2 options to avoid this

> use an extra container so img is not direct child of a flexbox in order to avoid unwanted behavior in webkit
>
> use an older method like float.

---

Oldish float method  :)

```css
#header-text {
  font-weight: 700;
  font-family: 'pduregular';
  color: #000;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 160px;
}
#header-text img {
  height: 160px;
}
#header-text span {
  float: right;
  margin: 0 10px;
}
#header-text .first {
  float: left;
}
#header-text::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 90px;  /* half height img (letter) + half height line */
  border-bottom: 20px solid;
  box-sizing: border-box; /* so it is average middle from height calculation */
  overflow: hidden; /* mind the floatting span */
}
/* let's see where it stands */

#header-text {
  background: linear-gradient(to left, transparent 50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 50%), linear-gradient(to top, transparent 50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 50%)
}
::after {
  opacity:0.5;
  }
```

```html
<div id="header-text">
  <span class="first"><img src="http://s-p-o-k.se/web/wp-content/themes/spok/images/Oo.svg"></span>
  <span><img src="http://s-p-o-k.se/web/wp-content/themes/spok/images/M.svg"></span>
</div>
```

---

extra wrapper  around image : *I let you try it yourself ;)* **okay i guess i shoud provide it too if i wish some feed back , so here it is:** :)

```css
#header-text {
  font-weight: 700;
  font-family: 'pduregular';
  color: #000;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 160px;
  display:flex;
}
#header-text img {
  height: 160px;
  margin:0 10px;
}
#header-text .first ~ span {
  display:flex;
  flex:1;
}
#header-text .first ~ span:before {
 content:'';
  flex:1;
  border-bottom:20px solid;
  margin:auto;
}
/* let's see where it stands */

#header-text {
  background: linear-gradient(to left, transparent 50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 50%), linear-gradient(to top, transparent 50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 50%)
}
:before {
  opacity:0.5;
  }
```

```html
<div id="header-text">
  <span class="first"> <span><img src="http://s-p-o-k.se/web/wp-content/themes/spok/images/Oo.svg"></span></span>
  <span> <span><img src="http://s-p-o-k.se/web/wp-content/themes/spok/images/M.svg"></span></span>
  <span> <span><img src="http://s-p-o-k.se/web/wp-content/themes/spok/images/Oo.svg"></span></span>
  <span> <span><img src="http://s-p-o-k.se/web/wp-content/themes/spok/images/M.svg"></span></span>
</div>
```

Comment: The float doesn't work if there are more than two characters in the title. Wrapping the img in an extra div worked pretty well. However, now the last character is counted outside the maximum width and is misaligned.

Comment: Seems to work now! I added the code you said and just added some extra top margin for the weird Swedish Ö-character and it's working fine now. Thank you very much!!!

Comment: @MarcusBrunström, it does for the page linked with 2 single letters, else what about option 2 ? ... if still not third option could be to set flex:0.1; instead 0 for last span .... One thing IE6 did teach me, if you can't avoid the bug, avoid the method tha brings it up, you'll save up time